# JavaFX ComboBox value changed loop

Tags: javafx, combobox

I have a program with a ComboBox which changes a view. If there are unsaved edits and the user changes the ComboBox, a dialog warns them if they're happy to proceed, and if yes it changes the view... BUT if they say no, I want the ComboBox to revert back to the previous value.

I'm trying to only post code relevant to the problem to be succinct... the warning dialog code happens elsewhere (in my viewController class) and the current group is stored in a class my whole program can see (globalFields).

Here is the code, and as such the problem:

```
 @FXML
private void handleClassesComboBox(ActionEvent event) {

    if (classesComboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() != null) {

        if (viewController.ifUnsavedChangesUserHappyToLose()) {
            globalFields.setCurrentGroup(classesComboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
            setView();
        } else{
            classesComboBox.setValue(globalFields.getCurrentGroup());
        }

}
```

So if they are NOT happy to lose changes, I want to revert to the previous selection, but of course this causes a loop as this handleClassesComboBox method is triggered again due to the change.

I'm sure it's obvious, but I can't work out the logic to revert back without the dialog looping over and over.

Also it's my first question here so if I've missed anything or explained the obvious let me know!!

Thanks!

Vin

Answer (score 0):

You could just set a flag:

```
private boolean checkUserChange = true ;
```

and then

```
@FXML
private void handleClassesComboBox(ActionEvent event) {

    if (classesComboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() != null) {

        if (checkUserChange && viewController.ifUnsavedChangesUserHappyToLose()) {
            globalFields.setCurrentGroup(classesComboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
            setView();
        } else{
            checkUserChange = false ;
            classesComboBox.setValue(globalFields.getCurrentGroup());
            checkUserChange = true ;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me unfortunately. It still loops round. Adding a System.out to check what the selected item is when it loops is revealing.... it seems to run twice the first time they "are not happy to lose changes", with the selected item changing back, but then changing AGAIN to what the user clicked on.... a 2nd time they press cancel as they're not happy to proceed, an exception in JavaFX App Thread, IndexOutOfBounds exception....

Comment: and if it helps, I added a System.out to check the flag state.... so, example:
Combobox was on X.... user clicks Y.... handle runs, with selected value of Y, flag true...... 
User presses no they're not happy to lose changes.... handle runs again, with selected value of X, flag false (all good so far), but then immediately flips back to Y again, as handle runs straight after , flag now true again, and as such the dialog appears again....
I don't know if that info helps... 
like the handle really doesn't like its value being changed mid-handle, it really wants to stick with user change!!

Comment: @VinNorman The the above but register a listener with the value property directly, instead of listening for an `ActionEvent`.

Comment: ok. please could you give me a clue as I'm still pretty new to this all... the comboBox is not bound to anything... so the value property of what? what would the line of code where I register it look like?

Comment: would it look like:
classesComboBox.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Object>() { ????

Comment: I was thinking `classesComboBox.valueProperty().addListener(...)` but I will test it out properly when I have time later.

Comment: great thanks, I'll have a play with this too, cheers for getting me started with this